# The HTML 'File' tag does not invoke the file browser on a Android device with cordova 6

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have  file tag where users can select file on android devices.. However, nothing happen when the button is press on the android devices..

Local Drive

can you please give some hints on how to fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: <input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.rdf,.txt,.pdf,.odt"
     onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)">
      <img src="assets/images/local_96x96.png"
       class="upload-image">
                        <p>Local Drive</p>

can you please give some hints on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File input type have issues with cordova as far as i know. Its advisable to use [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) for any file system related operations in cordova.